# Adding Advanced Custom Fields to posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

i'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugins and i want to display the fields on my posts. So i modified the single.php file of my theme like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><?php the_field('name_of_placement'); ?></li>
    <li><?php the_field('country'); ?></li>
    <li><?php the_field('timeframe'); ?></li>
    <li><?php the_field('types_of_healthcare_placement'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my test post:

http://electives-abroad.org/custom-field-test/

The only field that displays correctly is the "name of placement" field, the others display numbers, i don't know why.

*UPDATE*

The 'country' field is a taxonomy. According to this:
 advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy

I put the following:

```
<?php 

$term = get_field('country');

if( $term ): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
    <p>Color: <?php the_field('country', $term); ?></p>
```

But it doesn't show me anything –

*SOLUTION PROPOSED BY Sally CJ

```
    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
    <p>Color: <?php the_field('country', $term); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php the_field('name_of_placement'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('country'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('timeframe'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('types_of_healthcare_placement'); ?></li>
                </ul>
```

Now it shows me an "uncategorized".

*New update*

Now i tried this, to show 2 of my taxonomies: country and timeframe.

```
<ul>
                    <li><?php the_field('name_of_placement'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo get_term_field( 'name', get_field('country') ); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo get_term_field( 'name', get_field('timeframe') ); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_field('types_of_healthcare_placement'); ?></li>
                </ul>
```

Both of them appear as "uncategorized".

Comment: Seems like the other fields are not standard text fields. See [the ACF field types](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) and check which ones you used.

Comment: I updated the question. Please look.

Comment: To make your current code works, change the field's Return Value to Term Object.

Comment: Come again? i didn't understand.

Comment: Never mind. Try `$term = get_term( get_field('country') );`

Comment: I did it and know it shows me the post' category.

Comment: The answer might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the "country" field is a taxonomy field with a single value (i.e. the field's *Appearance* is radio buttons or a single-selection select/drop-down menu), and you want to display the term *name*, then you could use the [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/) function in WordPress:

```
<li><?php echo get_term_field( 'name', get_field('country') ); ?></li>
```

Or using `get_term()`:

```
<li><?php $term = get_term( get_field('country') ); echo $term->name; ?></li>
```

I hope that helps you.

### UPDATE

ACF may not be using the proper *post ID*, so try replacing the `get_field('country')` with this one:

```
get_field( 'country', get_the_ID() )
```

So:

```
<li><?php echo get_term_field( 'name', get_field( 'country', get_the_ID() ) ); ?></li>
```

### UPDATE 2

If you want to display the "country" *terms*/categories the post was assigned to, then:

```
<li><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country' ); ?></li>
```

would do it. You don't need ACF or any plugin to do that.. except maybe, you need a plugin for registering/creating the custom taxonomy and/or associating it to certain post types.

### UPDATE 3

Or... when you create/edit the ACF field, make sure to **select the proper taxonomy**, which in your case, I guess it's "Country" or "Countries"? *See the "Taxonomy" option below the "Required?" option on [this image](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/acf-taxonomy-field-edit.jpg)*

Comment: I edited the main post again, please look.

Comment: On the back-end, when you select an option for the `country` field, which means you selected a term (if the field is indeed a Taxonomy field), what was the option's label? Is it "uncategorized"? Try `var_dump( get_field('country'), get_field('country', get_the_ID()) );` - do you see same IDs?

Comment: object(WP_Term)#1826 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(13) "Uncategorized" ["slug"]=> string(13) "uncategorized" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(1) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(8) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

Comment: Okay, but just ignore that one and check my other comment or check the updated answer.

Comment: I did it and i get "Uncategorized" again.

http://electives-abroad.org/custom-field-test/

Comment: So it's not about the post ID. What is the correct one, if it's not "Uncategorized"?

Comment: The post is on the "Morocco" country, it should show that.

http://electives-abroad.org/country/morocco/

Comment: Does the "UPDATE 2" or "UPDATE 3" help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default `get_post_meta()` WordPress function

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID,  'country', TRUE)
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Where do i put that?

Comment: In single.php

`<li><?= get_post_meta( $post->ID,  'country', TRUE); ?></li>`

Comment: You can find current post id by `get_the_ID()` or use global $post for use $post->ID